# count peak values in a data window, kapacitor

Tags: monitoring, influxdb, kapacitor

I want to count the peak disc usage in a window of 5 mins.
I am new to tick script and kapacitor. this is the sample code. The thing is I only want to count in the active window (not the emitted 2 min window, even if it had some data points).

```
var curr = stream
|from()
    .measurement('disk_usage_root_used_percentage')
|window()
    .period(5m)
    .every(2m)
    .align()
// here i want the count to happen
|alert()
    .crit(lambda: "count" >5 )
    .log('/tmp/alerts.log')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q:**
How can I count the peak disc usage in a window of 5 minutes?

**A:**
What is going to happen when you specify `period=5m` and `every=2m` is that, Kapacitor will buffer up 5 minutes worth of point data and try to write it to its pipeline every 2 minutes.

So if the `stream` task were to go on for `10m`, you'll find that your TICK script will be executed `5` times in total.

For each execution window, the dataset will consists of `3m` of older data and `2m` of the newer ones. Essentially they are overlapped, this is bad because your use case here is to only analyse the latest `5m` point data and raise alarms if required, not looking back old data. In other words, you don't want to be spammed by false alarms.

To correct it, you will need to specify `.period=5m` and `.every=5m` for the `window` node. Doing so you'll find that the TICK gets ran twice upon 10 minutes up time, with each run consisting of the latest 5 minutes worth of data.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Your original question wasn't clear. So am I correct to say that you are only wanting to consider `peak` data for each window?

Comment: Say,my alarm threshold=5; in the first 5 min window, I had 2 peaks in the last 1 min. And in the next window I had 4 peaks in fist 2 mins. If I set every=5, I'm discarding the last one minute 2 peaks, and my alarming threshold(last 1 min 2+ current 2 mins 4, total 6) for that relative 5 min. That's why I gave every 2 mins.

Comment: Ok I see your problem. It seems like your data is sampling at 30s interval. Maybe your frequency or `every` should be set at 30 this is so that you don't miss anything. Downside is you could possibly get spammed by the alerts it continously hits `peak` for a bit. Do you think this works?

Comment: What's my goal is, I won't alert for a single spike, but for a count, say 5 in a window.

Comment: Yes. If you have `every=30s` and `period=5m` your 5 mins window will move at an interval of `30s` that way you won't miss anything. Trouble is if you hit an `alert` and the next 30s is a peak as well. You essentially get 2 alerts and it will keep coming through until the next sample is `non-peak`. Which is why I said you'll get spammed

Comment: I think it is not a bad thing for spam. Assuming this is for `devOps` purpose. You want your devops guys to respond to the continuous alarm right? As something is obviously wrong somewhere.

Comment: Yup! You got me... So, my doubt is using the default count(), will it only count the active window? Or will it keep data from the previous windows too ? Can you show me a sample logic to how to solve this problem, as you goty concern.

Comment: the `Count()` api will only handle data for the active window. As far as I am aware, Kapacitor task don't store data from previous window. I wish it could thou :P I think your TICK script is fine, I don't have any test data and requirements so it is difficult for me to write the TICK. Hope you understand.

Comment: Thanks man... Pleasure to meet u. I'm currently digging in kapacitor and the predictive alerting stuff. So I think I'll bug you more often.

Comment: No worries if you have other questions feel free to post it on Stackoverflow. If I have answered your queries will appreciate u mark this as answers thanks.